# Swift protocol conform: Candidate has non-matching type

Tags: ios, swift

I was trying to define a protocol with some property of type AnyObject, then in the class that conforms to the protocol the property type is SomeClass. However this returned a compiler error. I had to change the type in the class to AnyObject. How can I use the super class in protocol definition and use the sub class as property type?

Thanks!

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    var prop: [AnyObject] {get}
}

class Test: TestProtocol {
    var prop = [SomeClass]()    //compiler error
    var prop = [AnyObject]()   //this will work
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A playground example of what you can do:

```
class SomeClass {

}

class Subclass : SomeClass{

}

protocol TestProtocol {
  typealias T : SomeClass
  var prop: [T] {get}
}

class Test: TestProtocol {
  var prop = [Subclass]()

  func test(){
    prop.append(Subclass())
  }
}

let test = Test()
test.test() 
print(test.prop) // prints "[Subclass]\n"
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! That's it. typealias. I even thought about it earlier but didn't try bcz I couldn't figure out why I would need it instead of just using NSManagedObject as the super class...so why the typealias here?

Comment: I think specifying a concrete class is a strict constraint. So if you specify `AnyObject`, any class conforming to that protocol expects `AnyObject` and  not anything else. Using a generic type constraint in a protocol allows you to be more generic. The typealias is there to create the generic constraint in the protocol, otherwise we would again have a strict constraint. And you cannot just specify the generic constraint as `T` because T is unknown in the protocol scope, so that's not possible.

Comment: @the_critic Exactly so. I've expanded on this in my answer for the benefit of the OP, but my answer is merely a commentary on yours and is present only for education purposes.

Comment: @matt +1ed your answer for effort and making things clear.

Answer (score 14):

The array is an unnecessary complication, so let's remove it and just think about a simple type. This is not legal:

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    var prop: AnyObject {get}
}

class SomeClass {}

class Test: TestProtocol {
    var prop : SomeClass = SomeClass() // error
}
```

The problem is that the protocol declaration says quite literally that whoever claims to adopt TestProtocol must have a property `prop` *of type AnyObject* — not of some type that merely *conforms* to AnyObject.

If you find this surprising, you may be confusing instances of types with types themselves. It is true that an *instance* of SomeClass can be used where an *instance* of AnyObject is expected. But types *themselves* do not work this way; you cannot substitute the *type* SomeClass when the protocol demands the *type* AnyObject.

To see this more clearly, note that this *does* compile just fine:

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    var prop: AnyObject {get}
}

class SomeClass {}

class Test: TestProtocol {
    var prop : AnyObject = SomeClass() // changing the declared _type_
}
```

That compiles, as you already discovered; but, as you have also said, it is not what you wanted. So how to do what you want?

Well, in Swift, the way you express the notion of specifying a *type* that conforms to a protocol *type* is through a *generic with a constraint*. That is what the answers you've been given do. A `typealias` in a protocol declaration can be a way of making a generic protocol. And a generic can have a *constraint*, saying e.g. that the type in question should conform to a protocol or inherit from a class. Thus, this is legal and is the sort of solution you're looking for:

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    typealias T:AnyObject // generic
    var prop: T {get}
}

class SomeClass {}

class Test: TestProtocol {
    var prop : SomeClass = SomeClass() // :)
}
```

The line `typealias T:AnyObject` says that T must be a *type that conforms to AnyObject*, which is *precisely* what you are trying to say.

Comment: Thank you matt, that's very clear. 
What surprised me is that "you cannot substitute the type SomeClass when the protocol demands the type AnyObject", as declaring the subclass doesn't necessarily mean that this property conforms to the super-class defined in protocol.

Comment: And there's more where that came from: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_generics

Comment: @matt In Swift 4 the last snippet says `Type alias is missing an assigned type; use 'associatedtype' to define an associated type requirement`, but if I change it to typealias I get that dreaded `protocol 'TestProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`. Any ideas?

Comment: @AlexanderVasenin Sure, nowadays `associatedtype` is used instead of `typealias` to make a protocol generic. That's what I was showing the OP how to do — make this protocol generic. And sure, a generic type can't be used as the name of a variable type, only as a type constraint. Nothing new here. Don't use a generic protocol as a variable type! You couldn't then and you can't now (not yet, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid pushing the knowledge of the array element class up to the protocol by using a type alias requirement:

```
protocol TestProtocol 
{
    typealias ArrayElement: AnyObject
    var prop: [ArrayElement] {get}
}

class Test: TestProtocol 
{
    typealias ArrayElement  = SomeClass
    var prop:[ArrayElement] = []    //No compiler error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would do it with `associatedtype` in Swift 5:

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    associatedtype T: AnyObject
    var prop: [T] {get}
}

class SomeClass {}

class Test: TestProtocol {
    var prop = [SomeClass]()
}
```

Note that it works only if your `SomeClass` is a concrete type. This won't work if there was a protocol type instead. For example:

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    associatedtype T: AnyObject
    var prop: [T] {get}
}

protocol SomeProtocol: AnyObject {}

class Test: TestProtocol {
    var prop = [SomeProtocol]()
}
```